# Searching MongoDB arrays without respect for order

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, database

Given the following structure for entries in MongoDB:

```
{
_id: blahblah,
string_list: ['hello','large','world']
}
```

Is there a way to perform a search like:

```
db.test.find({string_list:['large','world','hello']})
```

that will return the any document which has `'hello'`,`'large'`, and `'world'` in the `string_list` field (but no other strings, just those three) in any order?

I know there is the `{$all:...}` 'operator' that will do something similar, but as far as I know if I used:

```
db.collection.find({string_list: {$all:['large','world','hello']}})
```

it would also return the following entry:

```
{
_id: blahblah,
string_list: ['hello','large','world','two']
}
```

which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$all` together with the `$size` operator, i.e.:

```
db.collection.find({"string_list" : {$all:["large","world","hello"]}, "string_list": {$size: 3}});
```

Comment: @CharlesSpinosa Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkbox next to the voting arrows.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Oops! Thanks for the heads up. Accepted